# onclick function not working into .append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to create the `div` tag using javascript and jquery. And i try onclick function apply to the `div` tag but this is not working?

```
var header = '<div id = "header" style="height:150px; width:500px; background:#a2a2a2;" ></div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',header);
$("#header").append('<div id="con" style="height:20%; width:30%; background:orange;" onclick="alert('hello world')"></div>');
```

IN the code i used onclick function inside the `div id="con"` tag not worked.? but Instead of i used

```
$("#header").append('<div id="con" style="height:20%; width:30%;  background:orange;" onclick="mufunc();"></div>');
function mufunc(){
alert("hello world");
}
```

In this code onclick function is working.

I need to alert the code inside the `<div>` How can i do it? What is the difference between the both function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the quoting. The `'` before `hello world` is matching the `'` that begins the argument to `append()`, so it's ending that string. You need to escape the quotes that are inside the string.

```
$("#header").append('<div id="con" style="height:20%; width:30%; background:orange;" onclick="alert(\'hello world\')"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

U can bind an onclick event  dynamically with **jQuery**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da" lang="da">
<head>
  <title>test of click binding</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(function(){
  close_link = $('<a class="" href="#">Click here to see an alert</a>');
  close_link.bind("click", function(){
    alert('hello from binded function call');
    //do stuff here...
  });

  $('.add_to_this').append(close_link);
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 >Test of click binding</h1>
  <p>problem: to bind a click event to an element I append via JQuery.</p>

  <div class="add_to_this">
    <p>The link is created, then added here below:</p>
  </div>

  <div class="add_to_this">
    <p>Another is added here below:</p>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the $("#header") line like this:

```
$("#header").append('<div id="con" style="height:20%; width:30%; background:orange;" onclick="alert("hello world")"></div>');
```

i just inserted (") instead of (') arount the hello world.

Answer (score 0):

You can do .click function of Jquery

`$(#con).click(function() {alert( "Handler for .click() called." );});`

Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/3v0e3c7s/1/)  a reference-style link to